# extract data between two tags but not the tags using java regex

Tags: java, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

```
 I have this list of 100 names to be extracted that lie in between the tags. I need to extract just the data and not the tags using Java Regular Expressions.
```

Eg: I need the data **Aaron,Teb, Abacha, Jui, Abashidze, Harry**. All in a new line.

```
    <a class="listing" href=http://eeee/a/hank_aaron/index.html">Aaron, Teb</a><br>
    <a class="listing" href=http://eeee/t/sani_abacha/index.html">Abacha, Jui</a><br>
    <a class="listing" href=http://eeee/i/aslan_abashidze/index.html">Abashidze, Harry</a><br>
```

I wrote the following code, but it extracts the tags too. Where am i going wrong. How do i replace the tags or Is the Regexp wrong.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    URL oracle = new URL("http://eeee/all/people/index.html");
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(oracle.openStream()));
    String input;
    String REGEX = "<a class=\"listing\"[^>]*>";
    while ((input = in.readLine()) != null){
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(REGEX);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
        while(m.find()) {
            System.out.println(input);
        }
    }
    in.close();
}
```

Comment: This has been [answered in depth](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/596781) before.

Comment: What @KerrekSB said. And please learn to *indent* your code so that it readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this regexp:

```
(?:<a class=\"listing\"[^>]*>)([^<]*)(?:<)
```

Its group 1 will capture the name.

P.S. You should move `Pattern p = Pattern.compile(REGEX);` outside the loop.

Comment: :Thanks for the answers. It did solve my problem. Thank You.